# Django-allauth does not use custom socialaccount templates

Tags: django, django-allauth

I copied the django-allauth account and socialaccount templates under

```
my_django_project/templates/account
my_django_project/templates/socialaccount
```

respectively. Allauth successfully reads the overwritten account templates but it does not read

```
templates/socialaccount/snippets/provider_list.html
```

my **settings.py** looks like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

The socialaccount templates are called in **login.html** with an include tag:

```
{% include "socialaccount/snippets/provider_list.html" %}
```

it looks likethe {% url %} tag works but {% include %} calls the original package template. How can I force {% include %} to look into the templates folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it has always been workin. The problem is that provider_list.html has an if condition

`{% if provider.id == "openid" %}`

and since this is false ( i still don't know why) the changed that I made withing the if condition don't appear.